What are the works built on the foundation of Christ in 1 Corinthians 3:12–15?

If any man builds on this foundation using gold, silver, costly stones, wood, hay or straw, his work will be shown for what it is, because the Day will bring it to light. It will be revealed with fire, and the fire will test the quality of each man's work. If what he has built survives, he will receive his reward. If it is burned up, he will suffer loss; he himself will be saved, but only as one escaping through the flames (1 Corinthians 3:12-15 NIV).

The terms "gold, silver, precious stones, wood, hay, straw" are obviously symbolic of works built on the foundation of Christ.  What works survive the fire and what works burn up?  Do the Scripture identify these (can be answered), or can it only be based on opinion (no valid answer for here)?

Paul is never afraid to mix his metaphors.  Just consider what we have in this chapter of 1 Cor 3 -

V5-9 - Evangelist's work likened to a farmer
V10, 11 - Evangelist's work likened to a builder
V12-15 - results of outreach in the judgement likened to a metalsmith's furnace
Christian church likened to a beautiful shrine/temple

Now to the OP's question about precisely what the various works and workmanship might be that are likened to various building materials.  Paul obviously does not say in this immediate context.  So, we cannot be certain.
However, there may be hints in other places such as:

Jude 21 - keep yourselves in the love of God as you await the mercy of our Lord Jesus Christ to bring you eternal life.
John 12:25 - Whoever loves his life will lose it, but whoever hates his life in this world will keep it for eternal life.
John 6:27 - Do not work for food that perishes, but for food that endures to eternal life, which the Son of Man will give you. For on Him God the Father has placed His seal of approval.”
Rom 5:21 - so that, just as sin reigned in death, so also grace might reign through righteousness to bring eternal life through Jesus Christ our Lord.
1 Tim 1:16 - But for this very reason I was shown mercy, so that in me, the worst of sinners, Christ Jesus might display His perfect patience as an example to those who would believe in Him for eternal life.
John 4:14 - But whoever drinks the water I give him will never thirst. Indeed, the water I give him will become in him a fount of water springing up to eternal life.”
Eph 2:20 - built on the foundation of the apostles and prophets, with Christ Jesus Himself as the cornerstone.  See also 1 Peter 2:6, 7, Luke 20:17, Mark 12:10, 11, Acts 4:11.

To summarize these messages, it appears that our work for Christ, as His disciples, must be:

based on God's love
based on God's mercy
based on what God gives us (not our own work)
be fed of the bread (the work of God) that comes from Christ
based on a solid belief and absolute trust in Jesus
come from the water of life that only flows from Christ Jesus.
Built in such a way the Jesus is the chief cornerstone.

This is the best I can do.


“Now if any man build upon this foundation gold, silver, precious stones, wood, hay, stubble;” (1Co 3:12, KJV)

I suggest that the meaning of those building materials will be found  within the chapter.
What is Paul addressing in this chapter?

“And I, brethren, could not speak unto you as unto spiritual, but as unto carnal, even as unto babes in Christ. I have fed you with milk, and not with meat: for hitherto ye were not able to bear it, neither yet now are ye able.” (1Co 3:1-2, KJV)

Paul is addressing babes in Christ. Their spiritual level is a restriction to what and how Paul was going to address them. Due to their spiritual quality, Paul had to address them as though they are not saved: as people of the world speak. He spoke to them as unto carnal. Paul went on to point out their carnality vis-a-vis envy, strife, divisions, party spirit. Hence, I suggest that this chapter focuses on there carnality and what produced these carnal behaviours. This is the light from which to see the metaphors used by Paul.

“For while one saith, I am of Paul; and another, I am of Apollos; are ye not carnal? Who then is Paul, and who is Apollos, but ministers by whom ye believed, even as the Lord gave to every man?” (1Co 3:4-5, KJV)

It seems to me that there were those who became saved via Paul's message as well as those who became saved via Apollos' message. There are two camps, based on who led them to Christ, within the church in Corinth. Paul says that they are "ministers by whom ye believed."

“I have planted, Apollos watered; but God gave the increase.” (1Co 3:6, KJV)

In verse 9, Paul says "...ye are God's husbandry...". Paul planted and Apollos watered on God's husbandry. God's husbandry are belivers. They are already in the kingdom. Paul planted and Apollos watered the beielievers.
In using another metaphor, Paul described these belivers as God's building vs 9. Henceforth, from verse 10 , Paul elaborated on these believers using the metaphor of a building. If these believers are a building, they are the different material products produced by Paul and Apollos that make up the building.
Hence, some believers in this church have been produced as gold, silver, precious stones, wood, hay and stubble. Again, this is just a metaphor to describe the believers in Corinth.
What made up these end-products of believers?
To answer this, the metaphor of farming and husbandry will have to be looked at again. Paul planted, Apollos watered these believers. vs 7.
It seems to me that what they taught these believers when each of them visited them produced the quality of believers, especially the carnal ones that Paul is dealing with here. They are the products of doctrines, teachings, instructions, corrections etc they received from the labourers. Doctrines, teachings, instructions, corrections, motivations, encouragements they taught fall into the categories of gold, silver, precious stones, wood, hay and stubble.
It seems to me that every believer is a product of what they have been taught! Those taught gold-like teachings become like gold. Those taught wood-like teachings become like wood in quality and usefulness and so on.

“If any man's work abide which he hath built thereupon, he shall receive a reward. If any man's work shall be burned, he shall suffer loss: but he himself shall be saved; yet so as by fire.” (1Co 3:14-15, KJV)

Just as these teachers who taught wood, hay and stubble quality teachings "...shall be saved; yet so as by fire." The believers who have received such teachings also, "...shall be saved; yet so as by fire."
The carnality shown by the believers in Corinth is a product of what sort of teachings they have received.
There is reward for what sort of teachings, doctrines and etc we churn out to God's building!
How do we and what do we plant in the hearts as well as how and what kind of water do we water God's husbandry?

I only edited corrections to spelling and a few typos. Such a good answer deserves to be 'polished' a little, in that regard!

@Anne. Thank you. I did the write up late in the night.

In the letter to the Corinthians, Paul begins with the issue of divisions in the church based on allegiances to human persons.
1 Cor. 1

12 Each of you is saying, “I belong to Paul,” or “I belong to
Apollos,” or “I belong to Cephas,” or “I belong to Christ.” 13 Is
Christ divided? Was Paul crucified for you? Or were you baptized in
the name of Paul?

In the second chapter he says:

1 When I came to you, brothers, proclaiming the mystery of God, I did
not come with sublimity of words or of wisdom. 2 For I resolved to
know nothing while I was with you except Jesus Christ, and him
crucified.

Then, in chapter 3 he gets to the meat of the matter:

5 What is Apollos, after all, and what is Paul? Ministers through whom
you became believers, just as the Lord assigned each one. 6 I planted,
Apollos watered, but God caused the growth. 7 Therefore, neither the
one who plants nor the one who waters is anything, but only God, who
causes the growth...10
According to the grace of God given to me, like a wise master builder
I laid a foundation, and another is building upon it. But each one
must be careful how he builds upon it, 11 for no one can lay a
foundation other than the one that is there, namely, Jesus Christ.

These readings provide the basis for us to answer the OP's question: The works that survive are the works based on Christ, and not those based on the human wisdom of Paul, Apollos, Peter or any other minister.

In Christianity, "Church" does not refer to a physical building. At its core, it refers to the assembly of Christians who believe in Jesus Christ as their Lord and Savior. This diverse community encompasses individuals from all walks of life - the wealthy, the educated, the average person, and those from the lowest rungs of society - all gathered together. Each believer's faith will be tested, as illustrated in 1 Corinthians 3:13

their work will be shown for what it is, because the Day will bring it to light. It will be revealed with fire, and the fire will test the quality of each person’s work.

Gold, Silver, costly stones, wood, hay or straw symbolize people from different backgrounds. The metaphor doesn't imply that gold will always endure while straw is destined to be consumed by fire. Rather, it emphasizes that anyone's work, if it fails the test, will be in vain.

I'm not posting this as the answer, but an answer.  I credited someone else with the answer.
When tested by fire gold, silver, or costly stones will survive. while wood, hay or straw will burn up.

Character which grows us closer to the image of Christ. (Rom. 8:28-30; 1John 3:2-3) The rest is discarded.

The positive relationships with other Christians. (1 Cor. 13:13) The negative is discarded. (Matt. 5:23-24)


